# Umbraco Database Query

Tags: umbraco

I want to add a property for a document type in Umbraco. After that, I want to add content using the newly edited document type. Finally, I want to edit the property value of the content and save it into the database. I want to do this using a SQL command in SQL Server Management Studio, given that I have installed Umbraco and I can access the Umbraco database.

Comment: Why do you want to create the Document Types and Content manually through SQL Server Management Studio? What is driving this requirement? Maybe we can help you find a better way. As Tim has said, important umbraco events won't get fired if you create content or doc types manually like this. There are also umbraco packages you can use to import document types and content into umbraco that might help. Check out CMS Import at http://soetemansoftware.nl/cmsimport and uSync at https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usync/. Maybe they can help.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do these things directly in the database with Umbraco. In fact, part of your requirements (adding content) wouldn't display on the front end if you did it in the database, as doing so would not fire the events needed to add your new content to the site XML cache.

Ideally you should be doing this in code, using the API. You don't mention which version of Umbraco you're using, so I'll assume the latest (7). That being the case, you ca use the various service APIs to accomplish your requirements. You'd use the ContentType Service to create your new Document Type, and the Content Service to add the content of your new type.

For more information, refer to the Umbraco services reference page: [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Services/)

Answer (score 0):

As Tim says it's not a good idea to do this with SQL, an alternative solution is to do it with a package. An Umbraco package contains an XML document, it is also possible there to make an adjustment in the XML (if the goal is a generated change)